# Will my baggage be sent through to my final destination?

Tags: transit, british-airways, turkish-airlines

I am flying from ELQ airport in Saudia Arabia to Istanbul (IST) on Turkish Airline and from Istanbul (IST) to London (LHR) on British Airways.

Do I have to claim and recheck my baggage in Istanbul or it will be checked through to my final destination in London?

Comment: Is it in one booking?

Comment: Yes it's ......

Answer (score 1):

Because the trip is in one booking and you do not change airports en route, your luggage will be checked through.